# Cover page height set to 100% has it halfway

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to implement a bootstrap cover page template, and I am struggle with setting it up. I literally was able to copy the code over to mine from bootstraps website, and it results in the cover page taking up half the height. In the styles, it clearly has height: 100%, but if I change the height to a different percentage, it won't affect it at all. However, if I change the height to 740px, it ends up being the relative height of the screen for me, but that will present issues in the future. Why is it that the height percentage won't affect it?

```css
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 740px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.cover-container {
  max-width: 42em;
}


/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */
.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */
.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

Comment: you should always post all the relevant code in order to get a good solution, please add the html code you are using to the question, and/or make a fiddle that shows your problem

Comment: What do you think `body { height: 740px; }` does, Betzel?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
html, body {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #aaa; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I wonder why it is that the 100% didn't work though..